# Adobe Air for iOS: MovieClip Animation runs at high framerate / FPS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

Having a strange issue with an Air for iOS project built with Adobe Animate (Flash) where a MovieClip [preload] animation is playing at a really high framerate while a netstream/netconnection video is loading.

The project itself has a framerate set to 17fps, and I've also attempted to set the framerate via as3 (using `stage.frameRate=17`) but for whatever reason, this animation always seems to play at a really high framerate (800-3000fps!) but will eventually level out down to 17.  This only seems to happen when I first open the app on the iOS device. If I call the same function again to play the video, then the animation plays back at 17fps.

I used the code at https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-build-a-frame-rate-counter-in-actionscript-30--active-3479 to determine the actual FPS it was playing back at (which is where I found out it was at around 3000fps in some cases!) and I've also tried using various code for framerate limiting/throttling to no avail (such as the class found here: http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2009/05/idle_cpu_usage_.html) and am running out of ideas..

The Air for iOS render mode is set to GPU, but changing to anything else has the same issue.  I've read a lot about low FPS issues with Air for iOS apps, but haven't come across anything similar to this issue yet and need to find out if anyone has had a similar problem and might know of a solution!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that you are playing the animation preload beofre FPS definitions were loaded, so it defaults. Please share your code so I can tell you how to fix this.

Comment: I managed to resolve this by manually advancing through the animation using a timer.  I honestly have no idea why it plays at a faster rate on iOS sometimes; Usually only when the app is first opened/first time the animation is called.